# Gathering cookies

Tags: php, firefox, cookies

I'm not even sure how to describe what I'm trying to do since I don't know a whole lot about cookies, but here goes.

Is it possible to use PHP to collect a cookie (or cookie file) from the browser cache, save it into the database, then clear the cache and re-save it back to where it used to be?

What would be involved in implementing this? Reading from the browser cache? Do I need to give it a path to where the cookies are saved, or can it automatically get it through communicating with the browser directly? Can PHP handle that?

Comment: `I don't know a whole lot about cookies`. it's ok. But do you happen to know what practical task you want to achieve? Why do you need all this cookie mess? If so, you'd better tell your *goal* instead of *the way* you choose.

Comment: Cookies are not stored in the browser's 'cache' - that's the term for where documents, scripts, css, images etc. are temporarily stored for quick access. Cookies are stored in a cookie file or database, usually, which is quite separate from the cache.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you can read all cookies from the user's system (that you are authorised to read) from the `$_COOKIE` array.

You can clear these cookies on the user's system by using `setcookie()` and setting them to a blank string, though you often need to know the exact hostname and path the cookies were previously set under, and give the same ones again, to be able to delete them properly.

You can then set the cookies again later to the values you previously got from the $_COOKIE array.

Not all in the same page view of course.

Answer (score 2):

Get cookie data:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["name"]) . '!';
?>
```

Assuming the "name" cookie has been set earlier
The above example will output something similar to:

```
Hello Hannes!
```

You could iterate over all cookies in the array with:

```
foreach($_COOKIES as $name => $cookie){
   echo "Cookie: $name has a delicious center consisting of: ";
   print_r($cookie);
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Set cookies:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP has nothing to do with client's computer in general and browser cache in particular.
PHP can get only the cookie, which browser send by it's free will and which were set by same server before.

Of course a server may send an empty or expired cookie which is equal to delete, or the same cookie with another value